# Частицы "не" и "ни"

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Подскажите, "не" или "ни" нужны в следующих предложениях. Кем бы вы себя (ни, не) считали, вы не можете себя так вести. Нельзя было так поступать, кем бы он себя (ни, не) возомнил.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае корректно написание с **ни**, поскольку частица **не** является отрицательной. В вашем же примере передается обобщенный смысл, **ни** усиливает утверждение.

> Кем бы вы себя ни считали (неважно кем), вы не можете себя так вести.
>
> Нельзя было так поступать, кем бы он себя ни возомнил.